# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am writing a messenger app that uses Firebase Firestore, Storage and Authentication. At first, opening it requests user data and if user with the number that the user entered exists then the application is getting his name and nickname from Firestore. But in this moment the app is stopping, responding and printing this message in logcat:

```
W/Firestore: (21.4.1) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds

This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

I am testing app on real device with Android 10 and this error appears only when application trying to get user data from firestore. Function that getting data from firestore:

```
fun getUserFromFirestoreAndInsertItInDB(number: String): MessengerUser = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val user = Firebase.firestore.collection("Users").document(number).get()
            .await().toMessengerUser()
        database.messengerUserDao.insert(user)
        user
}
```

toMessengerUser() function:

```
fun DocumentSnapshot.toMessengerUser(): MessengerUser {
    val name = data!!["name"] as String
    val nickname = data!!["nickname"] as String
    val number = data!!["phoneNumber"] as String
    val lastOnline =
        (data!!["lastOnline"] as Long) + Calendar.getInstance().timeZone.rawOffset
    lateinit var stream: InputStream
    Firebase.storage.getReference("UsersPictures/$number")
        .child(number).stream
        .addOnSuccessListener {
             stream = it.stream
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(it.cause!!)
        }
    val picture = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null)
    return MessengerUser(picture, name, nickname, number, lastOnline)
}
```

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App using Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the internet? Besides that, take a look at these [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Could+not+reach+Cloud+Firestore+backend).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to thread blocking with the await method.
Only Java: Same error with an ReentrantLock and RxJava's blockingGet() methods, but not with an CountdownLatch.